# Guard-Haml Compiles to Incorrect Output Directory

Tags: ruby, haml, development-environment, guard

Is [guard-haml](https://github.com/guard/guard-haml) still in development and use? The last commit seems to have been 5 months ago (not including updates to the README). I'm trying to get a simple input / output configuration working. However, the input directory always gets prefixed to the output location.

Ie "***resources/templ/documents/one.haml***" gets compiled to "*resources/public/**resources/templ/documents/one.html***". But all I really want is "***resources/public/one.html***". So for example, this configuration...

```
guard :haml, input: 'resources/templ/documents/' , output: 'resources/public/' do
  watch(%r{resources/templ/documents/.+\.(haml)$}) 
end
```

produces the incorrect output.

```
07:30:28 - INFO - Successfully compiled haml to html!
> [#] # resources/templ/documents/one.haml -> resources/public/resources/templ/documents/one.html
```

And these configurations produce nothing.

```
guard :haml do
  watch(/^.+(\.html\.haml)$/)
end

guard :haml, input: 'resources/templ/documents/' , output: 'resources/public/'  do
  watch(/^resources\/templ\/documents\/+(\.html\.haml)$/)
end

group :main do
  guard :haml, input: 'resources/templ/documents/' , output: 'resources/public/'  do
    watch(/^resources\/templ\/documents\/+(\.html\.haml)$/)
  end
end
```

Am I missing a proper configuration? Or is guard-haml (*Using guard-haml (1.1.0)*) just buggy? Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

FYI. I just solved this by having a simple one line configuration, without watchers. The watchers must be screwing things up.

```
guard 'haml', :input => 'resources/templ/documents', :output => 'resources/public'
```

Hth